# Magento change store view not working

Tags: magento-1.9

We have a magento installation and when editing categories and trying to change store view I dialog box appeared saying something about store view switching in categories I stupidly ticked and accepted or something. Now in my whole magento administration store switcher is working fine BUT in Manage categories it does not work. I can select a store view but it does nothing and the box with the selected store view just goes blank.

For example if I click at Manage Categiries, then I click on a category and I desire to change the properties of this category  for one of my store views this is not possible because as soon as I click on the category and then Choose a store view, the Store View dropdown select becomes blank and does nothing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran in to this and had to clear cookies from the adminhtml of my magento site.  At this point, the dialog started coming back and the selected store view is filled in again!

Still a little mysterious to me as to what is going on there though...

Comment: yes the same with me, but forgot to answer the question, since you did i will vote your answer. thanks